# Help with partitioning

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I am attempting to install Ubuntu alongise Windows on my laptop with a 128GB ssd. When I got to the step to partition the drive, I decided to allocate 25 GB for Ubuntu. But the computer froze.

I looked around and read that it's recommended to first run Ubuntu off of the flash drive and use GParted to partition my drive that way. So that is what I decided to do. However, when I got into GParted, I realized I was still a bit confused. Not sure which partition to select and which is what, so on.

[image: gparted screenshot]

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well if you want to install Ubuntu on that 128 GB SSD you are going to have to shrink Windows (from within Windows not within gparted) down from 118 GB to 70GB - 80GB or so as the first step.

Answer (score 0):

@WinEunuuchs2Unix is right - you have to shrink the Windows partition from inside Windows.

You should be able to find this option when you right click on My Computer -> Manage. In the new window you should see a left pane, one of those options should let you manage your disks. You should backup your data first before doing so as there is always a very small chance (but still happens) that the disk may be corrupted in the process.

After you have successfully shrunk the Windows partition, you should be able to use GParted to add a new partition to install Ubuntu on it (if you got confused by the UI, I am sure there is another AskUbuntu post that will talk about this ;) ).

Good luck